# SQL query to get the count based on month wise

Tags: sql-server-2012

This is login table where I need to display username with count they have logged in to application and split it by month wise the data to show the count based on month wise

Table name: **LoginInformation**

```
UserName   Count    Datetime
---------------------------------    
Test-1       1      2017-06-02
Test-1       1      2017-07-20
Test-1       1      2017-09-20 
Test-1       1      2017-09-20 
Test-1       1      2017-09-15
Test-1       1      2017-10-22 
Test-1       1      2017-10-23 
Test-2       1      2017-06-12 
Test-2       1      2017-06-12 
Test-2       1      2017-07-24
Test-2       1      2017-09-23 
Test-2       1      2017-09-29 
Test-2       1      2017-09-11
Test-2       1      2017-10-12 
Test-2       1      2017-10-19 
Test-2       1      2017-10-21
```

I need he result to be displayed as

```
UserName   Count     June July Sept Oct
----------------------------------------
Test-1       7        1    1    3    2
Test-1       7        2    1    3    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH ctePrepared AS (
    SELECT
       UserName
       ,TotalCount = SUM([Count]) OVER (PARTITION BY UserName)
       ,[MonthName] = DATENAME(MONTH,[Datetime])
       ,[Count]
    FROM
       @Table
)
ORDER BY
    UserName DESC

SELECT *
FROM
    ctePrepared t
    PIVOT
    (
       SUM([Count])
       FOR [MonthName] IN (January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December) 
    ) pvt
```

the test data script if needed:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (UserName VARCHAR(50), [Count] INT, [Datetime] DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES ('Test-1',1,'2017-06-02')
,('Test-1',1,'2017-07-20')
,('Test-1',1,'2017-09-20')
,('Test-1',1,'2017-09-20')
,('Test-1',1,'2017-09-15')
,('Test-1',1,'2017-10-22')
,('Test-1',1,'2017-10-23')
,('Test-2',1,'2017-06-12')
,('Test-2',1,'2017-06-12')
,('Test-2',1,'2017-07-24')
,('Test-2',1,'2017-09-23')
,('Test-2',1,'2017-09-29')
,('Test-2',1,'2017-09-11')
,('Test-2',1,'2017-10-12')
,('Test-2',1,'2017-10-19')
,('Test-2',1,'2017-10-21')
```

Comment: This works almost but missing the the column count where it holds the sum of all month

Comment: @Kumee so I did miss the total.  Easy way is to use windowed function in the cte, but you could also add all of the months as well (if did this part would have to account for NULL).  anyway I edited the answer.

Comment: Can you  help me with the query for this?  Matt

Comment: @Kumee help with what my comment?  I edited my answer to show how to incorporate look at the TotalCount column in the common table expression.

Comment: Your updated query runs with total that is fine can i  order the result by username desc and when null is displayed wanted have value as 'N/A'

Comment: @Kumee just add an order by clause I added one to show you how.  for N/A you would then be mixing data types so you would need to cast/convert from INT to string and then use either `ISNULL()` OR `COALESCE()` look up those and PIVOT to understand how to implement it.

Comment: Instead of 'N/A ' i am fine with value as '0'  can you assist me where to add i tired but query failed

Comment: Instead of 'N/A ' i am fine with value as '0'  can you assist me where to add i tired but query failed